# Changing Ionic Menu side dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to change the Ionic 3 Menu side dynamically once user changes the language.
For RTL languages menu needs to be on the right, by default it's set on left.

I subscribe to `TranslateService` from `@ngx-translate/core` event when the language changes `app.components.ts`:

```
this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
  console.info(`Language change to ${event.lang}`);
  this.isRTL = event.lang == 'ar' || event.lang == 'fa';

  if (event.lang == 'ar' || event.lang == 'fa') {
    this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
    this.menuSide = 'right';
  } else {
    this.platform.setDir('ltr', true);
    this.menuSide = 'left';
  }

  this.platform.setLang(event.lang, true);
});
```

The code above gets executed successfully when I the language gets changes and all the variables get set as expected (I've written unit tests to be sure and tons of console.logs while the app is running.)

In the template:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" [side]="isRTL?'right':'left'" side="{{menuSide}}">
....
</ion-menu>
```

However, even though the `this.menuSide` changes in the controller, it won't work as expected.

It seems the side can be changed only before `platform.ready()`, once the `platform.ready()` is done, no matter what I set it won’t take any effects.

**Edit**:

I've tried to use the method in https://stackoverflow.com/a/46417869/636136 but that didn't fix it too.

If I just print `menuSide` in the template it would have the correct value on the screen, but doesn't have any effect on the menu direction.

I can change the "side" attribute on the menu element manually via browser element inspector and it will change the direction successfully, however using `menuSide` variable won't do the job.

- Source code available at https://github.com/SavandBros/gonevis-mobile/blob/master/src/app/app.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to change the side of the `ion-menu` via `HTMLElement` directly.
I know this is not recommended and it should be handled the way I was trying to make it work in the original question, but that's all I could come up with after trying so many different ways.

I believe the problem I have with `ion-menu` and its behavior on changing the side is a bug.

Here's what I've changed to get it working.

`app.component.ts`

```
export class MyApp {
  #...
  menuSide: string = "left";

  this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      console.info(`Language change to ${event.lang}`);
      let element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById("lovelyMenu");

      if (event.lang == 'ar' || event.lang == 'fa') {
        this.platform.setDir('rtl', true);
        this.menuSide = 'right';
      } else {
        this.platform.setDir('ltr', true);
        this.menuSide = 'left';
      }

      element.setAttribute("side", this.menuSide);
      this.platform.setLang(event.lang, true);
    });
  }
  ...
}
```

`app.html`:

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" [side]="menuSide" id="lovelyMenu">
....
```

Answer (score 3):

alternate solution, simple, smooth and works like a charm

**In app.html**

```
  <ion-content class="ttct-app-side-menu-content">
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let page of menuPages" (click)="openPage(page)">
        {{page}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ng-template>

<ion-menu *ngIf="language === 'en'" type="overlay" side="right" [content]="content">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ttctSideMenuContent"></ng-container>
</ion-menu>

<ion-menu  *ngIf="language === 'ar'" type="overlay" side="left" [content]="content">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="ttctSideMenuContent"></ng-container>
</ion-menu>
```

**In app.component.ts**

```
this.translateService.onLangChange.subscribe((event: LangChangeEvent) => {
      if(this.translateService.currentLang === 'en') {
        platform.setDir('ltr', true);
      } else {
        platform.setDir('rtl', true);
      }
      platform.setLang(this.translateService.currentLang, true);
        });
.
.
.
.
.
  changeLanguage(lang) {
    this.translateService.use(lang);
    this.language = lang;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `property binding` instead of `interpolation`.

**i.e.** `[side]="menuSide"`

```
<ion-menu [content]="content" [side]="menuSide">
....
</ion-menu>
```

Comment: I've used that as well, that didn't work. I've tried millions of ways and none of them worked. If I open the element inspector, the value of side is still "left", even though I console log the value and it's "right". Thing is, if I initialize the "menuSide" before `platform.ready()` it will work but not after that. The full source code is available at https://github.com/SavandBros/gonevis-mobile/blob/master/src/app/app.html

Answer (score 0):

put SIDE key in json file for each lang like for example:

ar.json

> "SIDE" : "right",

and en.json

> "SIDE" : "left",

**and then in html**

```
 <ion-menu [content]="content" side="{{'SIDE' | translate}}"
```

....

Comment: No that doesn't work neither. weirdly nothing change on ion-menu tag no matter how many ways I've tried.