# How to add Direction ['ltr', 'rtl'] in ionic 4 dynamically?

Tags: angular6, ionic4

I have an ionic application which supports multiple languages. How can I do Change Direction dynamically?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Ionic Menu side dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46417847/608639)

Comment: Not a duplicate, they talk about Ionic 3.

Comment: This seems to have changed in Ionic 4, but I am also having difficulty in finding any documentation on this

Answer (score 0):

I think we can do it by,

```
document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl';
```

Answer (score 0):

Maby that helpfull

```
<ion-tabs mode="ios" dir="{{currentLanguage == 'en'?'ltr':'rtl'}}">
```

or

```
<ion-tabs mode="ios" [dir]="currentLanguage == 'en'?'ltr':'rtl'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private translate: TranslateService) {
    this.lang = localStorage.getItem('LANG');
  }

  languageChanged() {
    localStorage.setItem('LANG', this.lang);
    this.translate.setDefaultLang(this.lang);
    if (this.lang === 'iw')
      this.document.documentElement.dir = 'rtl';
    else
      this.document.documentElement.dir = 'ltr';
  }
```